# HD .mkv files - any hope for improvement in 18.04

Tags: graphics, video, intel-graphics, mkv

I am having difficulty running HD .mkv files in 17.04. I was wanting to upgrade to 18.04 but read that the graphics drivers don't work properly and have been downgraded in current releases. Is there another solution for my N2870 CPU? What is the future plan for Ubuntu 18?

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about a particular behaviour in a version you haven't installed yet, then you can download an iso of that version and [install it to a USB key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator) and run Ubuntu that way.

You can install packages in the demo and verify that drivers and things work the way you expect.

I can't speak to the specific concern about the N2870 other than to say that Intel made the active decision [to merge their graphics drivers directly into the kernel tree](https://01.org/linuxgraphics) recently which means that they are now built in to Ubuntu rather than requiring a separate install.  This means you should expect your graphics to work out-of-the-box and only need to install additional (in-tree) packages if you want something special like DRM or DVDCSS that are geographically controlled.

Comment: Does that mean there might be a difference between UEFI and Legacy installs?

Comment: Not as far as mkv functionality.  UEFI and BIOS are different ways of booting your system and have no functional effect once the kernel is running.